# Speech in Cocoa app through terminal

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Im trying to make a Mac application that speaks user inputed  `NSTextField` text using "system" to use the `say` command in terminal. However, Xcode keeps giving errors.

```
- (IBAction)speak:(id)sender{
    system("say %@", [textinput stringValue]);
}
```

*textinput is the `IBOutlet` of the `NSTextField`.

Comment: Is there any reason you're trying to get the system for this rather than the NSSpeechSynthesizer class?

Comment: NSSpeechSynthesizer class?, havnt heard of it before, how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System takes a single char* as an argument, so you have to format the command string before you can pass it to system:

```
- (IBAction)speak:(id)sender {
    NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"say %@", [textinput stringValue]];
    system([command UTF8String]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to call out to the system command, just use the Cocoa speech synthesis API directly. For example

```
NSSpeechSynthesizer* speechSynthesizer = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[speechSynthesizer startSpeakingString:[textinput stringValue]];
```

Then it's easy to set the voice and adjust other settings too.